# Как в Android активировать PUSH уведомления из VK API?

Tags: android

Нужно подписать устройство для получения PUSH, как мне это сделать?

[Вот метод](http://vkturbo.ru/dev/account.registerDevice)

Реквестом передаю токен:

```
VKRequest request = new VKRequest("account.registerDevice", VKParameters.from(VKApiConst.ACCESS_TOKEN, String.valueOf(VKAccessToken.currentToken().accessToken) ));
```

Но в ответ получаю:

```
VKError (API errorVKError (code: 100; ; One of the parameters specified was missing or invalid: token is undefined))
```

Comment: Тот `token` который `missing` в данном контексте, это не `access_token`, а `token` устройства, для отправки на него `push` уведомления.

Получить его не самая тривиальная задача, ознакомьтесь с документацией `gcm` https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start

Comment: Спасибо, как тут можно самому догадаться...
А что такое device_id там же?

Comment: нет, device_id постоянный для устройства. Вот как пример
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785485/is-there-a-unique-android-device-id